# Prevent daterange column from inserting 'empty'

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

In my `show_instance` table, I have a column called `dates` with type `daterange`.

```
CREATE TABLE public.show_instance (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    show_id integer NOT NULL,
    dates daterange NOT NULL
);
```

One of the values for dates is both inclusive and exclusive of day 2010-01-01.

```
INSERT INTO show_instance(id, show_id, dates)
VALUES
(1, 3, '[2010-01-01, 2010-01-01)'), 
(2, 4, '[2010-04-03, 2010-04-04)'),
(3, 5, '[2010-05-29, 2010-05-30)');
```

This insert statement throws an error: 
ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "show_instance" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 3, empty)

When all rows are selected, the daterange for the row is 'empty.'

```
SELECT show_id FROM show_instance WHERE daterange('2010-01-01', '2010-05-30') <@dates;
 show_id 
---------
(0 rows)

horse_show_db=# SELECT * FROM show_instance;
 id | show_id |          dates          
----+---------+-------------------------
  1 |       3 | empty
  2 |       4 | [2010-04-03,2010-04-04)
  3 |       5 | [2010-05-29,2010-05-30)
(3 rows)
```

For some reason, the 'empty' row is selected.

```
SELECT show_id FROM show_instance WHERE daterange('2010-01-01', '2010-05-30') @>dates;
 show_id 
---------
       3
       4
       5
(3 rows)
```

**1. Is there a constraint that prevents 'empty' from being inserted in the row? 

2. If 'empty' is not equivalent to 'null', what is it?**

Comment: The ettor you are showing has nothing to do with the empty range.

Answer (score 0):

"empty" is a special range value, representing a range that has no points. It's different from null because you can do operations with it, like a union with another range, which returns a non-null value.

You can restrict empty values with a constraint like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE show_instance 
ADD CONSTRAINT check_show_instance_dates_not_empty
CHECK (NOT isempty(dates));
```

Comment: The upper/lower functions still give you access to the underlying range elements - even in case of an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, empty loses the range boundary information.
I.e, [2010-01-01, 2010-01-01) is empty
[2010-02-01, 2010-02-01) is also empty
Can we differentiate between these two empties? (for audit)

Note: [x,y) means includes x, excludes y (x<=y)